# NoClassDefFoundError в springframework

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-mvc

При добавлении библиотек через maven получаю ошибку **NoClassDefFoundError**. 
При добавлении jar в WEB-INF/lib все работает норм.

Проблемы возникают например с библиотеками commons-fileupload-1.3.1, commons-io-2.4, jstl-1.2.

Использую:

- Intellij idea 2016.3,
- maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0,
- Tomcat 8.5.9,
- springframework 4.3.1.RELEASE

> Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [controller.FileUploadController]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>UploadMultiFiles</groupId>
<artifactId>UploadMultiFiles</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>config/application.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш pom.xml. Скорей всего проблема в настройках плагина для сборки.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman добавил в вопросе

Comment: Вы собираете ваш джарник без зависимостей. Естественно, что когда рантайм пытается использовать одну из них, он ее не находит.

Comment: @Etki не помогло, получаю `Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception` из-за этой ошибки. исправил в вопросе pom после изменений

Comment: Не помогло что? Вы все еще собираете без зависимостей. Более традиционным способом, насколько понимаю, будет закидывание зависимостей в /lib в tomcat, но никогда этим способом не пользовался.

Comment: @etki подскажите плиз что надо добавить что бы собирать проект с зависимостями. не совсем понял о чем мы говорим. спасибо.

Comment: Когда вы собираете проект через maven, в результирующем jar/war нет ничего из того, что указано в зависимостях, поэтому при запуске такого  jar/war выпадет аналогичная ошибка. Я предлагаю сделать fat jar (war) - в этом случае все зависимости упаковываются вместе с вашим кодом в один артефакт. Для джарников это assembly plugin или shade plugin, с варниками никогда такое не приходилось делать.

Comment: @etki спасибо. почему Вы не оформляете ответ)? я бы подтвердил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы при сборке WAR-файла все зависимости автоматически добавлялись в `WEB-INF/lib` результирующего файла, необходимо указать в POM-файле, что вы хотите собрать именно WAR, добавив строчку:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```